# Sitecore timeout on login

Tags: sitecore

Working with sitecore on my local machine.  When I attempt to log into "desktop", it hangs at /sitecore/shell/default.aspx?sc_lang=en and eventually times out.  It works fine if I log into "content editor" Any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: Is there anything interesting in Sitecore log file? Under /data/logs

Comment: Only a readme.txt with no text in it.  Thanks!

Comment: This is unbelievable... haha the fix worked for me shocked!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem once. The solution was to move the Data directory to a different location (with its whole content). I have no idea why it behave like that.

What's even stranger, once it starts working, you can move the folder back and it will behave as it should.

Comment: Do you mean the folder called "Data", or the one called "Databases", or some other folder?  Thanks!

Comment: He means the folder called "Data"

Comment: If this worked for you it would be nice if you mark my answer as correct ;)

Comment: This did not work for me but giving the IIS_IUSRS account access to the C:\Windows\Temp folder did the trick. See: http://wonald.com/common-sitecore-cms-bug-2-cannot-login-to-desktop-mode-437.htm

Comment: I had a same problem I could not able to run my Home page from content editor as well as I could not able to login in desktop mode . The problem fixed by after giving IIS_USERS, NETWORK_SERVICES etc to the C:\Windows\Temp folder ,

Answer (score 3):

We had this problem yesterday. We found this question on Stack Overflow and tried moving the data folder from the website folder into a separate folder. This solved the problem immediately. You then need to change this setting in the Sitecore.config (or Web.config) file:

```
<sc.variable name="dataFolder" value="/Data"/>
```

to point at the new folder.
We have asked Sitecore support whether this is a known issue and they didn't have many ideas. Their only guess was that it could have been caused by Sitecore caching.

Answer (score 3):

That's probably because your "datafolder" setting in the web.config is still pointing to the old location.  Change it to the new location and you will be all set.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have permission to comment on others answers yet, but just thought it's good to add my little experience about this problem.

I moved the data folder to somewhere else as @Maras suggested, then sitecore started complaining about can't find license file. If this is your case just simply move the data folder back, it then started working for me.

Comment: The License complaint was because Sitecore looks for License file under /Data/license.xml. As stated in the above answers, the trick is to change the dataFolder location in Web.Config.